# $ tx''+ x' - tx + f(t) = 0 $ with $\displaystyle f(t)=\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2^-}\Big(e^{-t(\sec{\theta})}\tan{\theta}\Big)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

A solution of this ODE is $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\sec{(\theta)}e^{-t\sec{(\theta)}}d\theta$ and I don't know how to start with the following ODE:
$$ tx''+ x' - tx + f(t) = 0 $$
with $\displaystyle f(t)=\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2^-}\Big(e^{-t(\sec{\theta})}\tan{\theta}\Big)$. Is this ODE possible to solve it?

---

**Note:** I don't know what is the value of $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2^-}\Big(e^{-t(\sec{\theta})}\tan{\theta}\Big)$, I am going to change this for the value when I know it.

Comment: The homogeneous linear ODE $tx_0'' + x_0' - tx_0 = 0$ can be written as the modified Bessel's equation by multiplying by $t$: $t^2 x_0'' + t x_0' - t^2 x_0 = 0$.
Thus the general solution is $x_0(t) = C_1 I_0(t) + C_2 K_0(t)$, with the zeroth-order modified Bessel functions $I_0, K_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{-t\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)=e^{-t/\sin(\epsilon)}\frac{\cos(\epsilon)}{\sin(\epsilon)}\quad;\quad \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon$$
$\theta\to(\pi/2)^- \quad;\quad \epsilon>0\to 0^+$
$$e^{-t\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)\sim \frac{e^{-t/\epsilon}}{\epsilon}$$
 $f(t)=\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2^-}\Big(e^{-t(\sec{\theta})}\tan{\theta}\Big) =
\begin{cases}
0\qquad \text{if}\quad t>0 \\
\infty\qquad \text{if}\quad t\leq 0
\end{cases}$

Thus the case $t\leq 0$ is excluded.

$$tx''+x'-tx=0\qquad t>0$$
This is an ODE of Bessel kind.
$$x(t)=c_1I_0(t)+c_2K_0(t)$$
Modified Bessel function of first and second kind.

Comment: This is a very interesant answer, thank you!!